# Rails 4 Scope Not Sorting Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

This is my first time using scope in rails.  I'm trying to sort a list of chapters by a field called `:priority`, an integer, in my Chapter Model.  I have looked over the scope documentation but I cannot seem figure out how to get the feature to work.

**Model**

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :book
 scope :priority_sort, -> { order(priority: :asc) }
end
```

**Controller**

```
@chapters = Chapter.all.priority_sort
```

**And the view**

```
<% @book.chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <%= link_to chapter.title, [@book, chapter] %>
<% end %>
```

**What the view currently looks like**
priority/chapter_title

```
  -15
  About the authors

  3
  Chapter 18 Equal pay

  -13
  Chapter 2 Overview

  -4
  Chapter 11 Non-exempt employees: determining work time

  -11
  Chapter 4 Workers not covered by the FLSA
```

**What the view looks like with a `default_scope { order("priority ASC") }`**

```
  -15
  About the authors

  -14
  Chapter 1 Snapshot

  -13
  Chapter 2 Overview

  -12
  Chapter 3 Covered employers

  -11
  Chapter 4 Workers not covered by the FLSA
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @book.chapters.each do |chapter| %>
 <%= link_to chapter.title, [@book, chapter] %>
<% end %>
```

Is this a mistake?  If not then it's because you're scoping on something in the controller you don't use.  I.e

`@chapters = Chapter.priority_sort.all`

If not then you can change it to

```
<% @book.chapters.priority_sort.each do |chapter| %>
  <%= link_to chapter.title, [@book, chapter] %>
<% end %>
```